# Creationism vs simple math

Tags: universe, creationism, creator

Zero is an abstract In the mathematical sense. There can’t be zero apples if apples didn’t exist to begin with.

So, in a sense the universe couldn’t of been created from zero without existing to begin with.

Doesn’t it disprove any kind of theory that has to do with creationism?

Comment: Zero is abstract: correct. Thus, if there were no apples "in the beginning" it makes no sense to speak of apples. Correct. But if there were an apple on my desk and I eat it, after that the number of apples on my desk is zero. Fullstop.

Comment: To speculate if "the universe couldn’t of been created from zero without existing to begin with" has no link with numbers and mathematics.

Comment: Looking around my room, there are zero unicorns, zero elves, and zero snuffleupagi (snuffleupaguses?), despite the fact that unicorns, elves, and... uh, whatever... don't exist. And if you say they 'exist' in my imagination, your argument about creationism implodes. I don't think this 'mathy' approach is going to get us anywhere.

Comment: @ Ted Wrigley - I understand your argument in regards to elves, unicorns... but the only way I can imagine them is by modifying my imaginations of things that already exist.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of a thing may exist even if the thing itself never has and never will.

One might even say that "There are zero unicorns" is true because, and only because, no unicorns exist.

This level of philosophy quickly descends to logic-chopping and wordplay based on terms precisely defined before the game begins. Such definitions need not, and almost invariably do not, reflect the broad and imprecise range of usages in everyday discussion.

Add theology to it at your peril.

Answer (score 0):

I think a creationist (I’m not one) would just say that you’re right, creation wasn’t totally from zero. First of all, the Bible doesn’t say creation was from nothing. Second, God did the creating, so he existed prior to creation.

There’s a problem with your reasoning, though. I can talk about zero splazoinkas, and splazoinkas don’t exist, so the mere fact of being able to talk about something doesn’t mean it somehow exists.

Comment: Assuming we are talking about elves, unicorns, hobbits....,  it’s true that by themselves they don’t exist, but the only way I can imagine them is by modifying my imagination of things that already exist. If I will ask you to define what is a splazoinka, you will have to use use notions that already exist.